# Funcion AJAX con VUE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, vue.js

quisiera saber de que forma se puede hacer el siguiente código pero con VUE, me gustaría incursionar en esta nueva tecnología pero no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre ella entonces me gustaría pasar la siguiente llamada ajax pero con VUE, ya tengo cargada la librería al proyecto.

```
    <script>
   $("#del-"+<?php echo $persona["id"];?>).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

    id = document.getElementById("id-"+<?php echo $persona["id"];?>).value//obtener valor del input


                                   var url = "enviar.php";
                                   $.ajax({
                                      type: "POST",
                                      url: url,
                                      data:{id:id},
                                      success: function(data)
                             {

                           }
                       });

                           });
    </script>
```

Comment: Vue es JS.. o sea.. no cambia nada.. la llamada la podes hacer exactamente de la misma forma.. que te gustaria cambiar en ese codigo?

Comment: Hola si lo que sucede es que he visto con VUE que es diferente y dicen que es mas facil aunque estoy confundido no se si el ajax que acabo de escribir depende de jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
data="{'id','id'}";
//nombre del metodo
getPersona(url,data) {
// puede ser post o get
  this.$http.post(url,data).then((response) {
  this.message = response;
});
```

Comment: Porfavor explica tu código!